# Two Tabulars Side by Side in Threeparttable

Tags: tables, threeparttable, sidebyside

I'd like to have two tabulars side by side in threeparttable environment which is also in table environment due to floating option. However I am getting the tabulars one on top of the other. I prefer explicitly to have the threeparttable environment because of the easier use of table notes. Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\caption{Participation Rates by Demographic Group} 
\label{participation_rates}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} \hline \hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{First Order Rates} \\
&       &       &  \\
&       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ mother's education} \\
&       & hs less & coll more \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{single} & black & 0.7983 & 0.6165 \\
& white & 0.6105 & 0.4144 \\
&       &       &  \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{married} & black & 0.3286 & 0.1946 \\
& white & 0.1938 & 0.1118 \\ \hline \hline 
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cccc} \hline \hline 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Order Rates} \\
&       &       &  \\
&       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ mother's education} \\
&       & hs less & coll more \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{single} & black & 0.6502 & 0.4230 \\
& white & 0.4547 & 0.2695 \\
&       &       &  \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{married} & black & 0.2789 & 0.1438 \\
& white & 0.1562 & 0.06453 \\ \hline \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item Here are some table notes...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Off-topic: the statement `\begin{threeparttable}` should be placed *before* the `\caption` statement. Why? The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the caption, a `tabular`-like environment, and the `tablenotes` environment.

Answer (score 5):

Enclose both four-column tables in an "outer", two-column `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Participation Rates by Demographic Group}
\label{participation_rates}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{cc} % <-- new
\begin{tabular}{cccc} \hline \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{First Order Rates} \\
&       &       &  \\
&       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ mother's education} \\
&       & hs less & coll more \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{single} & black & 0.7983 & 0.6165 \\
& white & 0.6105 & 0.4144 \\
&       &       &  \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{married} & black & 0.3286 & 0.1946 \\
& white & 0.1938 & 0.1118 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
 & 
\begin{tabular}{cccc} \hline \hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Second Order Rates} \\
&       &       &  \\
&       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ mother's education} \\
&       & hs less & coll more \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{single} & black & 0.6502 & 0.4230 \\
& white & 0.4547 & 0.2695 \\
&       &       &  \\
&       &       &  \\
\multirow{2}[0]{*}{married} & black & 0.2789 & 0.1438 \\
& white & 0.1562 & 0.06453 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular} % <-- new

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item Here are some table notes...
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As you've (re-)discovered, the `threeparttable` environment uses the width of the very first `tabular`-like environment to determine the width of the other two main elements -- the caption and the `tablenotes` environment. Because `threeparttable` expects to "see" just one `tabular` environment, it forces a line-break ahead of the second `tabular` environment in your code.

Assuming you want to keep the `threeparttable` machinery and hence must make it believe that there's just a single `tabular` for it to deal with, you could proceed as follows:

- Use [@Zarko's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529512/5001) and embed the two four-column environments in an "outer" 2-column `tabular` environment.
- Set up a single-column "outer" `tabular` environment and nest in it a `minipage` of width `\textwidth`. This approach is explained in greater detail below.

The second approach has an important advantag: it permits a natural use of `subtable` environments (provided by the `subcaption` package). The following code shows how this might be done. Note how I've given both tables more explicit visual structure and that it's no longer necessary to resort to `\footnotesize` to "squeeze" both tables next to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit}

\usepackage{booktabs,subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=0.25\baselineskip} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\begin{threeparttable}

%% Part 1 of 3: the caption
\caption{Participation Rates by Demographic Group} 
\label{tab:participation_rates}

%% Part 2 of 3: the tabular-like structure
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} % dummy "outer" tabular env.
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\caption*{First Order Rates} 
\begin{tabular}{@{} llcc @{}} 
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{mother's education} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
& & hs\slash less\tnote{a} & coll\slash more \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{single\tnote{b}}  
   & black & 0.7983 & 0.6165 \\
   & white & 0.6105 & 0.4144 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{married\tnote{c}} 
   & black & 0.3286 & 0.1946 \\
   & white & 0.1938 & 0.1118 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\caption*{Second Order Rates} 
\raggedleft % flush to right-hand edge of text block
\begin{tabular}{@{} llcc @{}} 
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{mother's education} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-4}
& & hs\slash less\tnote{a} & coll\slash more \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{single\tnote{b}}  
   & black & 0.6502 & 0.4230 \\
   & white & 0.4547 & 0.2695 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{married\tnote{c}} 
   & black & 0.2789 & 0.1438 \\
   & white & 0.1562 & 0.0645 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\end{minipage}
\end{tabular} % end of dummy "outer" tabular env.

%% Part 3 of 3: the tablenotes environment
\smallskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[a] Some notes \dots
\item[b] Some more notes \dots
\item[c] Still more notes \dots
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```